# How to make a progressbar for a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I need to send around 500 emails with `mail()`. It takes 500 loops.

How can I echo the percentage of the progression?

```
$percentage=55; //which changes every time it enters loop.

<div id="percentage" style="width:<?php echo $percentage;?>%></div>
```

Comment: So you're using PHP's `mail()` function. What does that have to do with a MySQL query?

Comment: email is being fetched from mysql database

Comment: Without using AJAX, you can't do this in PHP. All execution of the PHP page will wait until the loop you're using to send the mail has finished. Investigate the use AJAX.

Comment: Does anyone know a similar Ajax code. i am not very good at ajax.

Comment: You need to do your own research and reading. SO isn't a go-to solution for your programming code ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
($nb_send * 100) / $total
```

- **$nb_send**: The iterate value
- **$total**: your 500 emails

For your bar use the tag [progress](http://html5demo.braincracking.org/demo/progress.php)
Or in HTML => http://jsfiddle.net/zYewc/2/

Comment: i have calculated the percentage but it only displays after all the query has been executed.

Comment: is there a way to display the percentage every time it enters the loop

Comment: I've edited my post, look the progress bar or use two divs nested.
The first for the wrapper bar
The second with a background color and the width in percent

Comment: but my code comes in while loop. and the value changes every time its in loop. but it only shows 100% after full execution

Comment: Use Ajax for call a php script which will send email and return a status 0 or 1 for each email send.
Then in Js, get the status and fill the progress bar.
(sorry for my english i'm french...)